Grouping text with regex
consider I have a text like :
Some text 1
`special text`
Some text 2

I can get "special text" with regex, but I want other parts of the text too as an array, something like this :
[
  Some text 1,
  special text,
  Some text 2
]

I've tried below pattern, but I think it's not the answer
/(.*)\`(.*)\`(.*)/gm


We can try using the following regex pattern:
`.*?`|.+

This pattern says to match:

.*? a term inside backticks
| OR
.+ any other content

The trick here is to eagerly first try to find a backtick term.  Only that failing, we consume the rest of the line.


var input = `Some text 1
\`special text\`
Some text 2`;

var matches = input.match(/`.*?`|.+/g)
                   .map(x => x.replace(/^`|`$/g, ""));
console.log(matches);




thanks , is "?" necessary in pattern ?

@EhsanHatefi Yes, it actually is, because suppose you have more than one term in backticks.  In that case, if you just use .* it would match across all backtick terms.  We don't want that behavior, we want to capture until the nearest closing backtick.

If you want any text between the backtick at the start and the end of the string, you could use replace with a capture group:
^`(.*)`$

Explanation

^ Start of string
`(.*)` Capture any character between 2 backticks
$ End of string



const str = `Some text 1
\`special text\`
Some text 2`;

const regex = /^`(.*)`$/gm;
const result = str.replace(regex, `$1`).split("\n")
console.log(result);




For not allowing any backticks in between, you can use a negated character class to exclude matching a backtick (and a newline if you don't want to cross lines):
^`([^`\n]*)`$



const str = `Some text 1
\`special text\`
Some text 2`;

const regex = /^`([^`\n]*)`$/gm;
const result = str.replace(regex, `$1`).split("\n");
console.log(result);




For getting multiple matches in a single line, assuming there are no other single backticks, and a lookbehind is supported in your environment, you could match either all chars other than a backtick or match the same but then between backticks  using lookarounds:
[^`\n]+|(?<=`)[^`\n]*(?=`)

Explanation

[^`\n]+ Match 1+ chars other than a backtick or a newline
| Or
(?<=`)[^`\n]*(?=`) Match optional chars between 2 backticks



const str = `Some text 1
\`special text\`
Some text 2`;

const regex = /[^`\n]+|(?<=`)[^`\n]*(?=`)/g;
const result = str.match(regex)
console.log(result);




([^`]+): Matches any text that is not within backticks.
`([^`]+)`: Matches text within backticks.


const text =  'Some text 1 \`special text\` Some text 2';

const regex = /([^`]+)|`([^`]+)`/g;
const matches = [];
let match;

while ((match = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
  matches.push(match[1] || match[2]);
}

console.log(matches);




It doesn't appear you need a regex for this. To create the array, split() the string by the newline entity, after removing the extra ` characters:


const input = `Some text 1
\`special text\`
Some text 2`;

const output = input.replaceAll("`", "").split(/\n/g);
console.log(output);



